# Set Focus on Office-UI-Fabric-React Control in Dialog

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

I'm trying to set the focus on a UI Fabric `ListItemPicker` in a UI Fabric Dialog when it opens.

I'm using the following code:

```
    export default class MslTownProfilesWebPart extends React.Component<IMslTownProfilesProps, IMslTownProfilesState, {}> {
      constructor(props: IMslTownProfilesProps) {
        super(props);
        
        this._dialogRef = React.createRef();
        ...
       }
```

then

```
       <Dialog
          ref={this._dialogRef}
          hidden={this.state.hideDialog}
          onDismiss={this._closeDialog}
          dialogContentProps={{
             type: DialogType.close,
                title: 'Enter a town',
          }
          modalProps={{
              isBlocking: false,
              styles: { main: { maxWidth: 450 } },
          }}>
          <ListItemPicker 
               listId='<deleted>'
               columnInternalName='MSLTownsName'
               keyColumnInternalName='Id'
               orderBy={"Id desc"}
               itemLimit={1}
               onSelectedItem={this._onSelectedItem}
               context={this.props.context} />
           <DialogFooter>
                <PrimaryButton onClick={this._viewTownProfile} text="View" />
                </DialogFooter>
       </Dialog>
```

then

```
    public componentDidUpdate(){
        const node = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this._dialogRef.current.props.children[0]);
        node.focus();
      }
```

It is finding the `ListItemPicker` element but it appears not to have a focus method.

I've tried:

```
    const node = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this._dialogRef.current.props.children[0]) as HTMLDialogElement; 
    
    const node = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this._dialogRef.current.props.children[0]) as HTMLElement;
    
    const node = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this._dialogRef.current.props.children[0]) as HTMLUnknownElement;
```

But I get the error:

> 'Argument appears to not be a ReactComponent.'

Any ideas?